# SharePoint common files ... where to download?

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I do not have access to a SharePoint server but I have to prep a .net site to run on SharePoint 2007.  As per this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297200%28v=office.12%29.aspx

I need files in:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\12\ISAPI

Since I don't have access to a SharePoint server I have been googl'n for hours to try to find them.

Does anyone know where I can get them?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for SharePoint 2010, you can setup the whole thing on your dev machine. Read the MSDN article on the setup [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).

If you are developing for SharePoint 2007, I strongly recommend that you setup a virtual machine and install SharePoint on it (win server 2003 or win server 2008) It will save you a lot of time. Sure, by setting up the DLLs (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and the others) you would be able to build, but you won't be able to run anything, test anything, etc. It is a bit of an investment, but I really think that you'll end up saving some time in the long run (even if the run isn't that long).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run SharePoint 2007 then you'll need to install it on the server. Just copying the system root files you mention will not be enough.

Depending on the features you require you can use the free Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 or you can purchase Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) 2007.